# python global parameters file

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a python script that calls multiple functions from other scripts. I call the script giving it as a parameter a settings file with the format:

```
var1 = XXX
var2 = YYY
...
```

I would like to make those variables global so they can be used by every function I call, but without having to pass them explicitely. What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: you can just put them in a `settings.py` module and import that module

Comment: and they will be available to every function I import on the main script?

Comment: Yes, via `settings.var_name`.

I suggest using environment variables if it's a system' you're building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is using a settings (e.g. `settings.py`) module as suggested.

You simply define the variables in the module and they will be available to any module that imports the `settings` module via `settings.var_name`.

Example:

file `settings.py`:

```
var_name = "value"
```

file `m.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import settings
print settings.var_name
```

A preferred way is using the environment (child process inherits the environment) to pass it in a global context. You can use [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-parameters) for this purpose.

An example of how to do it:

file `a.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import b
os.environ['var_name'] = 'value'
b.echo()
```

file `b.py`:

```
import os

def echo():
    print os.environ['var_name']
```